# Move Selection to next word using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some html text i.e.

```
This is line1
```

I can get the initial user selection using `window.getSelection()` assume it is 'This'. On a click of a button, I like the user selection to move to the next word i.e. 'is'. How can I do this? I currently have the following code which does not work:

```
function myFunction()
{
var selection=window.getSelection();
selection.collapse(selection.focusNode, 0);
selection.modify("move","forward","word");
selection.extend(selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffSet);
}
```

and this is't good for me, because even the earlier word stays selected

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
```